# Javascript change variable from another function

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Hello I have this function right here:

```
function formCheck() {
  var valid = true;
  var error;
  resetBorders('.customer-create-form');

  $('.customer-create-form :input[required]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
          valid = false;
          error = "* Alle felter skal udfyldes";
          $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
      }
  });

  if ($('input[name="postal_code"]').val().length != 0 && !$.isNumeric($('input[name="postal_code"]').val())) {
      valid = false;
      error = "* Ugyldig post nummer";
      $('input[name="postal_code"]').css('border-color', 'red');
  }

  if (valid == true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    $('.error-firm-settings-1-form').html(error);
  }

  return false;
}
```

I want to set this into a function for itself, but when I do it and update the valid to false, the `formCheck()` does not register it, and it continues. How do I do so it set it to false in the `formCheck()` function.

```
  if ($('input[name="postal_code"]').val().length != 0 && !$.isNumeric($('input[name="postal_code"]').val())) {
      valid = false;
      error = "* Ugyldig post nummer";
      $('input[name="postal_code"]').css('border-color', 'red');
  }
```

Comment: Try to define arguments to the function. Call the function with the form parameters you are trying to validate.

Comment: Hmm can you give me an example, I think i doesn't understand what you mean?